# Set a test collection variable accessible for each request test in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

In Postman, after each request I execute this sequence of code almost every time in the test:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
// Do something useful with jsonData variable
```

Is it possible to put this declaration inside the collection test so that I can use it in each of my request test without having to rewrite it every time ?

Currently, if I set it inside my collection test and then try to use the variable `jsonData` in my request test, the variable doesn't exist.

I could set it in a global variable or environment variable I guess, but this seems not to be the right way.

Comment: Something like [this feature request](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2790) ?

Comment: My understanding is as follows.
I would say this has to do with [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scope/info). The variable `jsonData` is created and _dies_ for every request. The contents of `pm.response.json()` are different for each request, and it therefore _must_ be recreated for each request. More in [_no, that is not possible_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66197992).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables#accessing-variables-through-scripts) data variables as JSON should be used as global/environment variables:

> The Collection Runner lets you import a CSV or a JSON file, and then use the values from the data file inside HTTP requests and scripts. We call these ’data variables’.
>
> To use them inside Postman, follow the same syntax as environment or global variables.

So use  `pm.environment.set()` or `pm.globals.set()` for your `jsonData`

Comment: This is not an answer to the posted question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to put this declaration inside the collection test so
> that I can use it in each of my request test without having to
> rewrite it every time ?

*No, that's not possible.*
Read on if you want to know how I came to this conclusion.

---

I made a simple little experiment. You can replicate it as below.

I have created a Postman collection by the name `TestCollection`.
It can be downloaded and saved to your local drive from:
https://user.it.uu.se/%7Ehesc0353/postman/TestCollection.pm_coll.json.

Then - from the Postman desktop app (not the chrome extension) - the
`TestCollection` can be imported as shown in the figure below.
(*Collections* > *Import* > *File* > *Upload Files*)

[image: Import the collection 'TestCollection'.]

---

To open *the collection window*, click on the three mini circles (•••)
next to the collection name.
Then click **Edit** as in the figure below.

[image: Open the collection window of 'TestCollection'.]

---

As shown below, click the **Tests** tab.
The JavaScript snippet for the test of *the collection* is:

```
pm.test('Collection Test', function () {
  pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
console.log('Hello from Collection Test!');
const jsonData = pm.response.json();
console.log('Collection Test says URL = ' + jsonData.url);
```

The `// Do something useful with jsonData variable` in the question is
in this case to print the URL of the request in the console.

[image: 'Tests' prints the URL of the request in the console.]

---

Next click on the `TestCollection-Request` ...

[image: Opening the 'TestCollection-Request'.]

... and then on its **Tests** tab.
(The GET request is `https://postman-echo.com/get`
– Click the image to make it larger.)
The JavaScript snippet for the test of *the request* is:

```
pm.test('Request Test', function () {
  pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
console.log('Hi from Request Test.');
const jsonData = pm.response.json();
console.log('Request Test says user-agent = ' +
    jsonData.headers['user-agent']);
```

This time, the `// Do something useful with jsonData variable` in the
question is to print the `user-agent` of the request in the console.

Click the blue <kbd>Send</kbd> button ...

[image: Send the 'TestCollection-Request'.]

---

... and then open the `Console` in the bottom left corner.

The output in the console shows that *the collection test runs before
the request test*.

[image: The collection test runs before the request test.]

---

To answer the question asked, in *the second* JavaScript code snippet
(belonging to *the request*) we should comment out the declaration
(and initialization) of the `jsonData` variable, and then see what
happens when the request is sent again.
The result of doing this is shown the figure below.

[image: ReferenceError: jsonData is not defined.]

As the figure shows, this results in a
*ReferenceError: jsonData is not defined*.

I think it is rather obvious what is going on here. Once the scope of
*the second* JavaScript code snippet becomes alive, the scope of
*the first* JavaScript code snippet (belonging to *the collection*)
is already dead.
This means that - in *the second* code snippet - the `jsonData`
variable *is not available*.

---

To confirm this result, consider what will happen if - in the second
code snippet only - we (uncomment line 5 and) rename the `jsonData`
variable to say `otherJson`.
See the result in the figure below.

[image: The variables 'jsonData' and 'otherJson' ar unrelated.]

Confirmed! - Even though `jsonData` of *the collection* snippet and
`otherJson` of *the request* snippet contain *the exact same data*,
they are still two completely different and unrelated JavaScript
variables belonging to two completely different and unrelated scopes.
Think of the two code snippets being in two different files, if that
helps.

---

#### References

- [Postman: The Easy Way to Work with APIs](https://blog.postman.com/postman-the-easy-way-to-work-with-apis/)
- [Types of Scope](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-scope-and-scope-chain-in-javascript-f6637978cf53#df44)